# Syntax error: expected expression before ‘do’

Tags: c, gcc, syntax-error

I am trying to compile this software package: http://sourceforge.net/projects/snap-graph/?source=dlp

I hit a syntax error here:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../include   -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -malign-double -fstrict-aliasing -ffast-math -MT drive_seed_community_detection.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/drive_seed_community_detection.Tpo -c -o drive_seed_community_detection.o drive_seed_community_detection.c
drive_seed_community_detection.c: In function ‘identify_comm’:
drive_seed_community_detection.c:214:14: error: expected expression before ‘do’
make[2]: *** [drive_seed_community_detection.o] Fehler 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/amd.home/home/s/workspace/snap-0.4/test'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/amd.home/home/s/workspace/snap-0.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The relevant code section where the error appear is. In particular, line 214: `queue[atomic_fetch_and_add (&k2, 1)] = w;` Any ideas what might be the problem?

```
  /* Find and label the connected components. */
  ncomm = 0;
  for (attr_id_t kseed = 0; kseed < num_seeds; ++kseed) {
    attr_id_t k1, k2;
    const attr_id_t seedv = seeds[kseed];
    if (membership[seedv] != -2) continue;
    queue[0] = seedv;
    membership[seedv] = seedv;
    comm_root[ncomm] = seedv;

    k1 = 0;
    k2 = 1;
    do {
      const attr_id_t qkend = k2;
      attr_id_t cv = 0;
      OMP("omp parallel for reduction(+:cv)")
      for (attr_id_t k1i = k1; k1i < qkend; ++k1i) {
        const attr_id_t v = queue[k1i];
        const attr_id_t deg = xoff[v+1] - xoff[v];
        cv += deg;
        if (deg > comm_maxdeg[ncomm]) comm_maxdeg[ncomm] = deg;
        for (attr_id_t k = xoff[v]; k < xoff[v+1]; ++k) {
          const attr_id_t w = xadj[k];
          attr_id_t memb;
          if (membership[w] < -1) {
            atomic_val_compare_and_swap (memb, &membership[w], -2, seedv);
            if (memb < -1) {
              //if (membership[w] < -1) {
              //membership[w] = seedv;
              //int loc;
              //OMP("omp atomic") loc = k2++;
              queue[atomic_fetch_and_add (&k2, 1)] = w;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      k1 = qkend;
      comm_vol[ncomm] = cv;
    } while (k1 != k2);
    comm_size[ncomm] = k2;
    ++ncomm;
  }
```

Comment: What is `atomic_fetch_and_add`? A macro probably?

Comment: If `atomic_fetch_and_add` is a macro using the `do { ... } while (0)` idiom, it's designed to be used in a context where a statement is allowed; it can't be used as an expression. (In that case, the `do` is from the macro expansion.)

Comment: @KeithThompson That's where the error comes from. It is not my project, so I cannot fix it, but I was able to compile by commenting the line. I consider the problem solved.

Comment: @cls: Hmm. I'm skeptical that it will work correctly with that line commented out. You might want to contact the authors of the package.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh I'm sure this function is broken now. It's just a temporary fix to get it to compile at all. Will contact the developers about this error eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are bumping in appears only if the sources are compiled without OpenMP support.

Possiblities on how to patch the source to also comple in this situation were already provide by other answers.

Another approach to solve the OP's problem would be to enable support for OpenMP prior to compilation.

This can be done by passing the appropriate option to the configure script:

```
snap-0.4$ make clean    
snap-0.4$ ./configure --enable-openmp
```

This should produce the following output:

```
snap successfully configured! Please verify that
this configuration matches with your expectations.

   User Option                         Value          
------------------------------------------------------
   OpenMP support                      yes
   Enable debug                        no

...
```

Then compiling the sources using a simple

```
snap-0.4$ make
```

should work seamlessly.

---

**Note**

This would only work for compilers having `#define`ed:

- `__GNUC__`

or/and

- `__INTEL_COMPILER`

Comment: All answers were really helpful, but this one solves two problems at once.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing on the basis of the comments to your question. Given its name, it seems that

```
atomic_fetch_and_add(&k2, 1)
```

is an atomic version of `k2 += 1`, i.e. an operation that is guaranteed not to be interrupted between the moment when `k2` is read and the moment when its value incremented by one is stored back in `k2`. If this assumption is true, you could try replacing the line:

```
queue[atomic_fetch_and_add (&k2, 1)] = w;
```

with the following two lines:

```
atomic_fetch_and_add (&k2, 1);
queue[k2] = w;
```

Answer (score 1):

(Copying and expanding from comments.)

Given the context of the compilation error:

```
queue[atomic_fetch_and_add (&k2, 1)] = w;
```

and the error message:

```
drive_seed_community_detection.c:214:14: error: expected expression before ‘do’
```

it's very likely that `atomic_fetch_and_add` is a function-like macro defined using the `do { ... } while (0)` idiom, as described in question 10.4 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Such a macro is designed to be usable in a context that requires a statement, but cannot be used in a context that requires an expression.

Probably the developer used a system where `atomic_fetch_and_add` is defined so that it can be used in an expression context (it probably expands to an expression that yields the incremented value of `k2`).

[Lorenzo Donati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856268/827263) suggests a possible workaround: putting the invocation of `atomic_fetch_and_add` on a line of its own.

A less portable workaround might be to take advantage of a gcc-spoecific extension: *statement expressions*, [described here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). You could probably replace

```
queue[atomic_fetch_and_add (&k2, 1)] = w;
```

by

```
queue[({atomic_fetch_and_add (&k2, 1); k2;})] = w;
```

I do not recommend this approach, but if you have a lot of occurrences of this problem it might be easier to apply semi-automatically.

I'd also recommend contacting the developers of the project so they can fix this error.